# mySQL php PDO error 1054

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysql-error-1054

yesterday I had a question for mySQL syntax. It was how to have multiple WHERE statements. I am getting error1054. It is "Unknown column in 'Field List'". I have found out how to get the code to execute, however I cannot get it to work programatically (I have to go in afterwards and add in some quotes)

This is my output to my php:

```
clientid=andv025075
```

Here is my php:

```
<?PHP include 'connect.php';

$client = $_POST['clientid'];
try{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('
        SELECT * FROM accounts where isonline = 1 AND clientid <> :clientid
        ');
    $stmt->bindParam(':clientid', $client);
    $stmt->execute();

        $i = 0;
    $aOutputArray = array();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
    {
        $aOutputArray['users'][$i] = [
            'clientid' => $row['clientid'],
            'username' => $row['username'],
            'theme' => $row['themeset'],
        ];
        $i++;
    }
    echo json_encode($aOutputArray);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "noone_online";
        }
?>
```

What is happening(?):

```
SELECT * 
FROM accounts
WHERE isonline =1
AND clientid <>  andv025075
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

What needs to happen:

```
SELECT * 
FROM accounts
WHERE isonline =1
AND clientid <>  'andv025075'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Now, I am wondering why the statement won't execute with the binded params, because that should automatically recognize it as a string and compare the strings? Why do I need to add quotes to it? And, how should I put these quotes in? I tried to add the quotes directly from the client and send, but they get converted to ASCII

Comment: As a 3rd parameter of bindvalue, add PDO::PARAM_STR